# Tabbing text next to equations in a tabularx environment

Tags: tables, tabularx, alignment, text

I want to add aligned text after equations in a tabularx environment. I found methods using `align` or `alignat` but it seems impossible inside a table.

This is my current situation :

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm] 
{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=teal]{hyperref}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\makeatother
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{tabularx}{0.9\linewidth}{l@{}c@{}X}
\hypertarget{1.7.1}{\textbf{1.7.1}} & $\quad$ & For every matrix $A$ the matrix 
transformation $T_{A} : \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m}$ has the following 
properties for all vectors $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ and for every scalar $k$ :
\end{tabularx}

\begin{tabularx}{0.9\linewidth}{l@{}c@{}X}
$\qquad$ (a) $T_{A} (\mathbf{0}) = \mathbf{0}$ \\
$\qquad$ (b) $T_{A} (k \mathbf{u}) = k T_{A} (\mathbf{u})$ \null\hfill 
$\bm{\text{[Homogeneity property]}}$ \\
$\qquad$ (c) $T_{A} (\mathbf{u} + \mathbf{v}) = T_{A} (\mathbf{u}) + T_{A} (\mathbf{v})$ 
\null\hfill $\bm{\text{[Additivity property]}}$ \\
$\qquad$ (d) $T_{A} (\mathbf{u} - \mathbf{v}) = T_{A} (\mathbf{u}) - T_{A} (\mathbf{v})$ 
\\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

I am using `\null \hfill` but it looks bad. How can I align text to the left, with enough spacing after the equations?

Results that I want :

[image]

[image]

Comment: Off-topic: Don't load both `enumerate` and `enumitem`. Load one or the other, *but not both*. Suggestion: Use the `enumitem` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this? Observe the use of a single `tabularx` environment and of a bespoke `enumerate`-like environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper,vmargin=2cm,hmargin=3cm,
            marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
%\usepackage{enumerate} % don't load both 'enumerate' and 'enumitem'
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{myenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[myenum]{label=(\textit{\alph*}), left=0pt, 
                 align=left, topsep=0pt, itemsep=0pt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=teal]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{1\linewidth}{@{} lL @{}}
\hypertarget{1.7.1}{\textbf{1.7.1}} & 
For every matrix $A$, the matrix transformation $T_{A} 
\colon \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m}$ has 
the following properties, for all vectors $\mathbf{u}, 
\mathbf{v}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and for every scalar $k$:\\
& \begin{myenum}
  \item $T_{A} (\mathbf{0}) = \mathbf{0}$ 
  \item \parbox{0.3\textwidth}{$T_{A} (k\mathbf{u}) = kT_{A} (\mathbf{u})$}
        \quad [\textbf{Homogeneity property}] 
  \item \parbox{0.3\textwidth}{$T_{A} (\mathbf{u} + \mathbf{v}) 
        =T_{A} (\mathbf{u}) + T_{A} (\mathbf{v})$}
        \quad [\textbf{Additivity property}] 
  \item $T_{A} (\mathbf{u} - \mathbf{v})
        =T_{A} (\mathbf{u}) - T_{A} (\mathbf{v})$ 
  \end{myenum}
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```